# In SBT, what else should I do to add a folder/jar to the runtime classpath?

Tags: sbt

I'm trying to make an activator seed identical to [play-angular2-typescript](https://github.com/joost-de-vries/play-angular2-typescript) but using **akka-http** instead of **play**.

The problem I have is that, after removing the play plugin, the public assets folder (by default is "projectBase/target/web/public/main") disappeared from the runtime classpath. So, I have to add it manually. Therefore I have added the following line to the "build.sbt":

```
(managedClasspath in Runtime) += WebKeys.assets.in(Assets).value
```

But apparently, that is not sufficient. At runtime, the `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` doesn't include the public assets folder.

So I checked the project builder, by means of the `consoleProject` command, if the folder was actually added to the fullClasspath setting, and it confirmed that it is present: The list given by the following expression includes the public assets folder.

```
scala> fullClasspath.in(Runtime).eval foreach println
```

Then, what else should I do? Is the `Attributed.metadata` field relevant?

os: windows 10, sbtVersion: 0.13.11, scalaVersion: 2.11.8, jdk: 1.8.0_45

Answer (score 0):

I tested the behavior of adding folders to the `managedClasspath` setting in a new empty project and it works fine. So the problem was other obscure thing.
So I copied line by line of the non working project to the new empty one, testing every time, until discovering the bug.
It is the line

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-sbt" % "sbt-core-next" % "0.1.1")
```

which I have no idea what does, except trouble.
Removing it everything works fine.